Pythagorean diatonic scale vs pure notes
I am new to music theory, and was looking at the history of tuning. I got intrigued by Pythagorean tuning, and the subsequent adoption of equal temperament. So I tried to derive them myself. This was my thought process:

Why 12 notes? Since the Pythagorean scale is based on perfect fifths, to match octaves and fifths, we must have x = (3/2)^n = 2^y for some positive integers n and y, where n is the number of notes in an octave. Obviously, the only solution is n=y=0, with which is not feasible because we must have at least one note in the octave. Therefore, we can try making it as close to zero as possible. If y could have been any real number, we could have had y = n (log(3/2)/log(2)). Because no integer y would satisfy that, we can approximate by rounding it off to the nearest integer.

We would also prefer being able to play more notes, but only up to a limit. For example, 2 notes in an octave would be too few to produce meaningful music, 500 notes would be too many (unless you are a big big fan of microtonality). So suppose we follow the following requirments: minimise |x|, and favour more notes in an octave as long as the number does not exceed k, where k can depend on personal choice. For me, k = 20 is a good number.

When I tried doing this, trying all the numbers from n = 1 to 20, I found the following: the lowest values of |x| are given, in that order, by n = 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 7, 12 and so on. The best is with 2 notes in an octave, but that would be too few notes to produce music meaningfully. It is still a good candidate. The next is 5. 1, 3 and 4 all perform worse than 5 in terms of having higher |x| and also offer the musician fewer notes to play. Thus, 5 is better than them in both the metrics. And it struck me how extremely common pentatonic scale is across folk music systems of the world, and I thought, "ahha, this must be the reason". The next candidate is 7. And then I thought, "ahha, maybe that is why we have 7 pure notes". And the next best candidate is our good old 12 notes in an octave

After that, I thought, it must be the case that if I generate the Pythagorean notes step-by-step, the first 7 notes generated would be the pure notes, and if I keep going (insisting on having a few more notes), then I will get the full set of 12. And later, the names must have just stuck even after shifting to equal temperament. So I checked that.

This is what I did: start with a base note, with frequency X. The next note is (3/2)X. The next would have been (3/2)(3/2)X, but it exceeds 2X, so I bring it down an octave to get (1/2)(3/2)(3/2)X. The next note would be (3/2)(1/2)(3/2)(3/2)X and so on. Basically, multiplying the previous note by (3/2) and then dividing the result by 2 as many times as required to keep the new note within the range X and 2X, that is, in the same octave.

Then I arranged the resulting 12 notes in the ascending order of frequency. I tried labelling them: the lowest is Do, then Do#, then Re, Re#, Mi, Fa, Fa#, Sol, Sol#, La, La#, and Ti. I hoped that after the labelling, the pure notes would turn out to be the first seven notes generated in order in step 5. But that did not happen. The first seven notes generated were Do, Re, Mi, Fa#, Sol, La, Ti. Everything is as expected except that Fa# that has showed up instead of Fa.


So, my question is this:
a. Either my guess of where the idea of the 7 pure notes come from is wrong and there is some other reason for calling these particular notes pure, or I have misunderstood how Pythagorean tuning works and have wrongly constructed the scale. Which one is it?
b. If the former, then why are those particular notes called pure notes? And what is the historic progression from 7 to 12 notes like, if at all that is how it happened? Or is it the case that the first seven notes generated were called pure notes earlier, but then when the Pythagorean system was abandoned, the classification of pure and impure notes changed for some reason? If the latter, then how to correctly construct the notes in Pythagorean tuning?
I was very happy seeing 5, 7 and 12 show up like that in the ordering, but now wonder if it is a coincidence or it actually has something meaningful to say

I'm getting a lot of Google results for "pure note" meaning a one-wavelength, pure sinusoidal note instead of what you've got. If by "pure note" you mean a note notated in English without accidentals (i.e. the notes in the C major scale), here's your food for thought: the first note to get an accidental was B flat, to the point that German calls B flat "B" and B "H" instead.

"there is some other reason for calling these particular notes pure": who calls them pure?  What do they mean by this?  I've never heard of the term before.  Also, Pythagoras developed a theory to explain music.  Music was not generated from the theory.

@Dekkadeci Oh ok I googled after your comment and realised you are right. Here in India the term "pure notes" is often used for the ones without accidentals, I thought this is done everywhere. My guess then is that the Western music teachers in India borrowed the term from Indian classical music informally. Indian classical has 7 "shuddha swara"s or pure notes, which are, perhaps by coincidence, the exact same ones as the English without accidentals. I thought it's the same everywhere, turns out it isnt. See the section on the seven swaras https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svara

@phoog Yes of course music isnt generated from Pythagoras' theory. I was happy seeing it being able to explain common patterns in music I see around me, like in cultures around me 5, 7 and 12 notes in an octave are common (I come from a place that has both a lot of Indian and Chinese+ SE Asian influence in music). For the question of who calls them pure notes, see the comment above.

The invention of accidentals is typically traced to Guido of Arezzo in the early 11th century, who was the first to publish a system with two different B notes, one round and one square.  The first is the ancestor of the flat sign, while the second is the ancestor of both the sharp sign and the natural sign.  At this time, the primary pitch of the scale was D, not C.  The Dorian mode, for example, was the first mode (and there was no mode at all that was associated with C).
If you place the natural notes in circle-of-fifths order, you get
F-C-G-D-A-E-B
There's D, right in the middle.
(Guido's system used a forerunner of the modern do-re-mi syllables, but its application was somewhat different, and there wasn't a one-to-one relationship between letter names and syllables, which is why this answer doesn't follow the question's lead in naming the notes.)
So one very significant part of the answer is that the scales being constructed at the time when Pythagorean tuning was in use in western Europe did not include the C major scale.
Another part of the answer is rather speculative on my part, but it explains your observation in a comment:

Indian classical has 7 "shuddha swara"s or pure notes, which are, perhaps by coincidence, the exact same ones as the English without accidentals

My speculation here is that both Indian and Western European music settled on this scale as a default because of the importance of bass drones (and, later in Europe, bass-driven harmony).  This of course also has the effect of moving away from Pythagorean tuning (with its 81:64 ratio for the third degree) toward so-called "just intonation" with its 5:4 third degree, aligned with the harmonic overtone series, and this put Europe, at least, firmly on the road to equal temperament (by way of many unequal temperaments whose primary purpose was initially to reconcile the difference between 81:64 and 5:4).
But western European harmonic music didn't firmly settle on the major scale as the default until sometime in the 16th or 17th centuries, long after Pythagorean tuning had been relegated to the role of an impractical historical curiosity.
If you're interested in reading about the history of the western European note naming system, the gamut, scales, modes, and so on, I recommend very heartily the answers posted by user Athanasius, especially answers to

Why is C the base note of standard notation and keys?
What scale were the very first modes based on?
Why are clefs associated with reference notes G, F and C?
Why is the lowest note in Standard guitar tuning an E?


The divisions of the octave that have the best approximations to the just perfect fifth can be computed from the continued fraction (see "Pianos and Continued Fractions"):
log_2 3 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 23, 2, ...].
This gives an infinite sequence of approximations 1, 2, 3/2, 8/5, 19/12, 65/41, 84/53, ... (these are values of 1 + y/n in your notation). Looking at the denominators, we get scales whose numbers of notes are 2, 5 (pentatonic), 12 (chromatic), etc. Each successive scale has a juster fifth, but at the cost of more notes per octave. Other attractive divisions come from the semiconvergents such as 11/7 = (3+8)/(2+5), giving a 7-note (diatonic, or rather equiheptatonic) division.
It appears that 12 notes is the most that the normal human ear can meaningfully handle. But you can find avant-garde musicians experimenting with further semiconvergents, such as a 17-note division, or even the next convergent, which gives a 41-note division.
